# Why does this Maven dependency for Hadoop prevent JSPs from compiling?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, hadoop

I've tested this a few times to confirm I'm not crazy. If I include this Maven dependency for Hadoop...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

...one particular JSP stops compiling. The JSP does not, to my knowledge, use anything in the Hadoop package. The error is:

```
An error occurred at line: [97] in the generated java file: [/Users/gwg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/Harmonizome/org/apache/jsp/template/dataset_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
```

Any theories as to how these two events are related?

## EDIT

Any suggestions, even shots in the dark, are appreciated. I can definitely replicate this. I've completely emptied out the JSP and the servlet. The error occurs if I run

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(Constant.TEMPLATE_DIR + "dataset.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Even if I completely empty out "dataset.jsp".

Comment: It looks like conflict with servlet-api version.

Comment: You mean hadoop-client uses a different servlet-api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that Hadoop does not support `servlet-api` 3.0:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9244